# Issue with react onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, giphy

My app has an onClick that should be rendering more gifs. However, it does it once and then stops. Also, the onClick deletes all the gifs that were already on the page. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.searchGifs('kittens');
  }

  searchGifs = (searchQuery) => {
    fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${searchQuery}&limit=12&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC`).then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          results: response.data,
        });
     });
  }



  searchMoreGifs = (offsetQuery) => {
    fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${offsetQuery}&limit=12&offset=${this.state.results.length}&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC`).then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          results: response.data,
        });
     });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <main className="app">
        <Header />
        <SearchForm startSearch={this.searchGifs} />
        <ResultList gifs={this.state.results} />
        <LoadMore gifs={this.state.results} searchMore={this.searchMoreGifs} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the onClick:

```
   class LoadMore extends React.Component {
    render(props) {
        return(
            <button onClick={this.props.searchMore}>Load More</button>
        );
    }
}


export default LoadMore;
```

Comment: You aren't passing `offsetQuery` to `searchMoreGifs`

Comment: and `this.setState({ results: response.data });` overwrites the old value of `this.state.results`.  Each time the button is clicked, the old data goes away.  Figure out how to append `response.data` to `this.state.results` before calling `setState`.

Comment: Do you mean in the render?

Comment: @user8227859 Yes. In `LoadMore` you bind the event handler, but you never pass `offsetQuery`. The array being reset after every search is easily fixable with spread syntax.

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry, I'm very new to this... is this what you meant?           
       class LoadMore extends React.Component {
 render(offsetQuery) {
  return(
   <button onClick={this.props.searchMore(offsetQuery)}>Load More</button>
  );
 }
}


export default LoadMore;

Comment: @user8227859 No. What is `offsetQuery` even supposed to be here? I'm not familiar with the Giphy API, but you have the bind the arguments or use an arrow function: `<LoadMore searchMore={() => this.searchMoreGifs(WHATEVER_OFFSETQUERY_IS)} />`

Comment: @AndrewLi  
searchQuery is supposed to generate the gif results based on user input. And the offsetQuery was intended to append more gifs of the same category after the onClick is triggered. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @user8227859 Well, let me attempt to fix the problem of overwriting gifs. In `searchMoreGifs`'s `setState`, do `this.setState(prevState => ({ results: [...prevState.results, ...response.data] }))`

Comment: @AndrewLi Thank you!! In order to have the newly loaded gifs to be a continuation of the old ones, I could use prevState.results instead of this.state.results?

Comment: @user8227859 Yes. `setState` is more of a request than an immediate change -- it's asynchronous. Using a callback with `prevState` as the first argument ensures you get the correct previous state.

Comment: @AndrewLi hmm... so the following should've worked?                             <LoadMore searchMore={() => this.searchMoreGifs(this.prevState.results)} />

Comment: @user8227859 No... I was talking about when setting state. Just use current state with `this.state.results`..

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `this.setState({results: something})` you completely overwrite the previous state of results.You want to take the array that is in `this.state.results` and concat it with the new results.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      // I also suggest moving the searchQuery to the state so it can be used in both the offset and the original search
      searchQuery: 'kittens'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.searchGifs(this.state.searchQuery);
  }

  searchGifs = (searchQuery) => {
    fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${searchQuery}&limit=12&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC`).then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          results: response.data,
        });
      });
  }



  searchMoreGifs = (offsetQuery) => {
    fetch(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${offsetQuery}&limit=12&offset=${this.state.results.length}&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC`).then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          // You were overwriting the old results with new data every time you ran this function
          results: this.state.results.concat(response.data),
        });
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <main className="app">
        <Header />
        <SearchForm startSearch={this.searchGifs} />
        <ResultList gifs={this.state.results} />
        {/* You also need to pass the offsetQuery to the LoadMore component so that the searchMore function can use it*/}
        <LoadMore searchMore={this.searchMoreGifs} offsetQuery={this.state.searchQuery} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

class LoadMore extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    const {offsetQuery, searchMore} = this.props
    return (
      <button onClick={() => searchMore(offsetQuery)}>Load More</button>
    );
  }
}


export default LoadMore;
```